# Onclick highlight my list row doesn't working

Tags: java, android, xml, background-color

Hello friends i have tried many different ways to highlight my listview but nothing works for me. i want to highlight my customlist view when i click on that and than open a new activity.

here is my xml file **list_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Selector style for listrow -->
<item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
 android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

here is my **gradient_bg_hover.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <!-- Gradient BgColor for listrow Selected -->
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#18d7e5"
      android:centerColor="#16cedb"
      android:endColor="#09adb9"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

**And gradient_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <!--  Gradient Bg for listrow -->
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#f1f1f2"
      android:centerColor="#e7e7e8"
      android:endColor="#cfcfcf"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

and my **_activity_setup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

help me

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the list-selector from your listview and instead, set the background for your item view:

Your listview:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@null" />
```

Your item view (for example):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey this doesn't work for me! May be i am also calling  onClickListener(). is that the problem why it isn't highlighting ?